# Accessing multiple images stored in database as a filename but stored in public folder of laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I needed to upload multiple image as an array and for that i set up my controller like this:

```
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Detail;

    class DetailController extends Controller
    {
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    //
    $data=Detail::all();
    return view('details.index',compact('data'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
    $data=Detail::all();
    return view('details.create',compact('data'));
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */

  public function store(request $request) {
       $input=$request->all();
    if($files=$request->file('images')){
        foreach($files as $file){
        $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('image',$name);

        $input['images']=$name;
    }
    }

  Detail::create($input);

    return redirect('/details');


    }
```

And my route is:

```
     Route::resource('/details','DetailController');
```

Doing so I have become to able store the selected images for upload form form in public folder ie, Public/image. But only one image is stored in database like this.[Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYGrQ.png) .
Is it okay if only one among the selected images stored in DB and rest are stored in public. If okay then how can i access/display all the images in the show page.
Thanks.

Comment: I see no function with insert query.

Comment: Isn't it done by model itself?.

Comment: @Amani I have a model called Detail, which is as follow:
                     <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Detail extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'agentname', 'price','location','address','description','images',
    ];
}

Doing So other all the attributes values are inserted .

Comment: Normally you have to put : `Detail::create($input);` inside a foreach loop since you have multiple rows , like this: `foreach($input as $row){ Detail::create($row);  }` if you want to skip the loop you can simply use `DB::table('Detail')->insert($input);`

Comment: to use `DB` class don't forget to add `use DB;`

Comment: @Amani As you suggested  i did make changes as:  public function store(request $request) {
           $input=$request->all();
        if($files=$request->file('images')){
            foreach($files as $file){
                Detail::create($input);
            $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move('image',$name);
            
            $input['images']=$name;
        }
        }
but this error came:Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `details....

Comment: @Amani and when i did the second method as:
public function store(request $request) {
           $input=$request->all();
        if($files=$request->file('images')){
            foreach($files as $file){
            $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move('image',$name);
            
            $input['images']=$name;
        }
        }

      DB::table('details')->insert($input);
   
        return redirect('/details');
}
thiserrorcame:SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_token' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `details` (`_token`,

Comment: can you add this line `dd($input);` just after `$input=$request->all();` and post the output you get.

Comment: @Amani This is what I got: 
array:8 [▼
  "_token" => "vgX8xTaBpfucZoztVwwPOfcPgG5xa9nHQCreP0JD"
  "agentname" => "ghfdsdfgh"
  "address" => "jhgfghj"
  "price" => "123456"
  "description" => "hgfdghjkjh"
  "location" => "jhgfdghjhg"
  "submit" => "Submit"
  "images" => array:3 [▼
    0 => UploadedFile {#167 ▶}
    1 => UploadedFile {#168 ▶}
    2 => UploadedFile {#169 ▶}
  ]
]
I selected three image.

Comment: so all of your 3 images have the same description, price, location ...?

Comment: actually its the description for one post and images are for that particular post. Can we do private chat or sth please :)

Comment: @Amani for eg. Say i have a product and i need to provide price, product name, its description and so on with its images(more than 2). Now at home page i will have that product listed for each product add and when i click any one product it takes me to its detail page where it shows all those things including images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
 public function store(request $request) {
    $input=$request->all();
    $images=array();
    if($files=$request->file('images')){
       foreach($files as $file){
          $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
          $file->move('image',$name);
          $images[]=$name;
       }
    }
    /*Insert your data*/
 foreach($images as $image){
    Detail::insert( [
       'image1'=>  $image,
       'description' =>$input['description'],
       'price' =>$input['price'],
       'address' =>$input['address'],
       'location' =>$input['location']
    ]);
  }

    return redirect('/details');
 }
```

Comment: It threw this error: ErrorException in DetailController.php line 87:
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: on my 87th line i have this:'description' =>$input->description,

Comment: and just for clarification upload of images would be more than three or whatever user wants to upload. And also i have only one attributes/field called images for image in my Detail model as commented above.

Comment: And if i do  dd($input); uploading 8 images the browsers gives this:
 array:8 [▼
  "_token" => "vgX8xTaBpfucZoztVwwPOfcPgG5xa9nHQCreP0JD"
  "agentname" => "jhgf"
  "address" => "hgfg"
  "price" => "kjuytre"
  "description" => "fghjhgf"
  "location" => "ghjhgfdghj"
  "submit" => "Submit"
  "images" => array:8 [▼
    0 => UploadedFile {#172 ▶}
    1 => UploadedFile {#173 ▶}
    2 => UploadedFile {#174 ▶}
    3 => UploadedFile {#175 ▶}
    4 => UploadedFile {#176 ▶}
    5 => UploadedFile {#177 ▶}
    6 => UploadedFile {#178 ▶}
    7 => UploadedFile {#179 ▶}
  ]
]

Comment: can you join the chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136973/laravel-sql-issues

Comment: and for the execption it was my mistake since `$input` is an array you have to get data like this `'description' =>$input['description']` .. see update

Comment: not enough reputation to join chat :P. can i do chat in any other social medias please.

Comment: see update for-each image insert a new row.. but i wonder if each image is a new row why you have many image column in your data table `images` ,`image1` etc ..

Comment: actually those were made to try another way. making each row for each image. but that didnt work . Okay Amani just forget whatever i did okay. Now lets say you have a site, on its home page there somewhere there there are lists of some products. now when any one product is clicked it will take you to its detail page where there will be its details like name, description, price, trademarks and images(any number of images).Now for this would you make a different table for image and establish relationship with product table or simply on product table you would make an image field accepting images